# Confusion on linking two array

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
    $arr1=array("jol","pop","hari","john");//the array count is not limited to 4
    $arr2=array('germany','america','holland','america');
    ?>
```

Now I want to link

```
Name: jol(1),pop(2),hari(3),john(2)

Address:germany(1),america(2),holland(3)
```

we get the name as `pop(2)`  and `john(2)` because both are of same country

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: jol(1) try to say that jol is from germany and so on

Comment: by guessing it ? Where does come the information on who belongs to which country ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to remove duplicates from the second array and assign an index from each element of the first array to the second array, assuming that the arrays are equal in length beforehand?

Comment: @vusan then you should restructure your query. It's easier if they are ordered by country.

Comment: Can't make sense of your question. Mind explaining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the two arrays will always have the same number of entries, you can do this with a code like this one:

```
for($i=0; $i<count(@arr2); $i++) {
    if(!isset($country[$arr2[$i]])) {
        $country[$arr2[$i]] = $i;
    }
    $link[$arr1[$i]] = $country[$arr2[$i]];
}
```

The first part of the loop stores indices of the first match for each country.  The second part finds the corresponding index for each name.

Naturally, you'll need to add error checking for cases when a country is not found for the user (e.g. the number of elements in arrays don't match).